# Coercion befuddlement in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Why does the following

```
class Test {
  @Test
  void go() {
    def foo1 = new MockFoo1() as Foo
    def foo2 = new MockFoo2() as Foo
  }

  interface Foo {}

  class MockFoo1 {}

  class MockFoo2 {}
}
```

Result in a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` on the foo2 coercion?

This only happens if I coerce 2 objects of 2 different types to the same interface during a single path of execution.  The groovy approved way of using closures or maps to achieve this kind of duck typing works fine.

Any light shed appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me... JIRA, maybe?

Comment: Oh really. I'll log a bug then. Thanks mate

Comment: What bug number was this logged as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug with the `ProxyGenerator` `adapterCache`. As a workaround, you can also use some Groovy trickery to make this work:

```
interface Foo {
    static a = {
        [MockFoo1, MockFoo2].each {
            it.metaClass.asType = { Class klazz ->
                try {
                    DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(delegate, klazz)
                } catch (e) {
                    def cache = ProxyGenerator.INSTANCE.@adapterCache.@cache
                    cache.each { k, v ->
                        cache.remove(k)
                    }
                    DefaultGroovyMethods.asType(delegate, klazz)
                }
            }
        }
    }()
}

class MockFoo1 {}
class MockFoo2 {}

def a = new MockFoo1() as Foo
def b = new MockFoo2() as Foo

assert a instanceof Foo
assert b instanceof Foo
```

Hope this helps!